# How to make select input shrink when browser is resized?

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple form. The usual: a label and an input. The goal is to create a simple and responsive form. Everything works ok, except when the form contains a `select` input that is too large. For some reason, the `select` input does not shrink when the browser is resized. The other inputs (input, textarea) do shrink as the browser is resized.

I've tried using max-width: 100% on the select input, as other people suggested here, with no success.

I've created a jsfiddle that explains everything:
https://jsfiddle.net/ampr41po/3/

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="form-main">
  <form action method>
    <div class="controlUnit">
      <div class="label">
        <label for="firstname">First name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="control">
        <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" autofocus value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controlUnit">
      <div class="label">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="control">
        <select id="name" name="name">
          <option value="1">Name goes here</option>
          <option value="2">Name</option>
          <option value="3">This is a very very very very very long name. The name is mwpekng erter erter erter 4et erter 4ertye rwe 45y 43 rt rty rty rt rty rty </option>
          <option value="4">Another name</option>
        </select>
        <span class="icon-item"></span>
        <span class="icon-item"></span>
        <span class="icon-item"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-main {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

.controlUnit {
  display: flex;
}

.controlUnit .label {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.controlUnit .control {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
}

select {
  max-width: 100%;
}

input#firstname {
  width: 100%;
}

.icon-item {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.icon-item ~ .icon-item {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to achieve this, unless you set the `width` off the `select` element explicitly. Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47620311/6313073) for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `width: 100%`, instead of `max-width: 100%` for `select` in your CSS code in order to have a responsive `select` element at all screen sizes.

Your approach to set `max-width: 100%` is wrong, because `select` elements are form control elements and thus have to follow some implicit rules. For instance, the width of a `select` element cannot be made narrower than its widest `option` when using `max-width`. That's made that way by the browser and there's nothing you can do to change it. So, unless you set the `width` explicitly, there is no other way to achieve a responsive design.

Check out the updated jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ampr41po/4/).

Comment: I really want it to keep the natural size of the select tag. But, your answer is good enough since it's the only way to shrink the select tag when the browser is resized. Thanks

Comment: For those interested, i've kept researching here and found another solution that works perfectly. I've added overflow to the parent select tag and i've used calc to remove the size of the icon from the select tag width ( calc(100% - 25px) ). Now, everything flows perfectly regardless of the size of the select tag. The only drawback (if you can call it a drawback) is that i can only put 1 icon. I can put more but then i need to use classes to remove the total width of the icons from the select tag. I prefer using one icon and use a menu to display more options. https://jsfiddle.net/ampr41po/5/

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @Marco. Thanks for sharing the other solution you found. I'm sure some people will find it interesting.